# How to combine textarea element values with JavaScript and see every rule as unique combination? (Example included)

Tags: javascript, merge, textarea

I've been trying to learn JavaScript these couple of days in isolation and using my time to develop a 'Word Merger' for a client. The idea is that users can type in keywords and by clicking the 'Merge' button it will spit out every combination possible. A working version of the idea can be seen here: [Merge Words by Toptal](https://www.toptal.com/marketing/mergewords).

I've written the following JavaScript code:

```
function mergeWords() {
  var first = document.getElementById('firstTextarea').value;
  var second = document.getElementById('secondTextarea').value;
  var third = document.getElementById('thirdTextarea').value;
  var allResults = first + ' ' + second + ' ' + third;
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  var textResults = document.createTextNode(allResults);
  element.setAttribute('id', 'allResults');
  element.setAttribute('class', 'text-muted');
  element.appendChild(textResults);
  document.getElementById('mergeResults').appendChild(element);
}
```

This code takes all the values of the textareas and "merges" them together in a single rule. In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLjtp.png) you can see my result. Right now it shows:

```
Amsterdam The Hague Rotterdam Barber Haircut
```

But I want this to change to:

```
Amsterdam Barber Haircut
The Hague Barber Haircut
Rotterdam Barber Haircut
```

**If a value** is added to (for example) the third textarea, let's say the value **men** is added. The results should be:

```
Amsterdam Barber Haircut
Amsterdam Barber Men
The Hague Barber Haircut
The Hague Barber Men
Rotterdam Barber Haircut
Rotterdam Barber Men
```

Hopefully I could make the idea clear enough and I would greatly appreciate it if someone would help me out.

Stay healthy,
Luuk

Comment: Aren't there supposed to be much more combinations? Why is barber constant in every result line?

Comment: @Ivan86 You mean that for example 'Barber Haircut Amsterdam' should also be a combination? This is not ideal because the tool is used for usable SEO keywords. So 'Amsterdam Barber Haircut' are usable keywords but 'Amsterdam Haircut Barber' and 'Barber Haircut Amsterdam' for example are not. Let me know if you meant something else. See the link on the top for an example of a working tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well well, if it isn't the Dutch Expat... Found your question while looking for a solution to one of my own problems but I decided to quickly fix you up a 'solution'.

The problem with your code is that you get the value's of each of the textarea's without splitting them at line breaks. This makes that all text in there goes into a single entry. The second issue you face is that you combine all value's in one result, creating one big line without splitting them up. The solution to that is to index every line in each field, and then combine them per entry.

I will be explaining my simple solution step by step:

```
<form action="" id="combiForm">

 <textarea id="textarea-1" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="Each enter makes a new input line..."></textarea>
 <textarea id="textarea-2" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="Each enter makes a new input line..."></textarea>
 <textarea id="textarea-3" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="Each enter makes a new input line..."></textarea>
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="separator" name="separator" placeholder="Input will be used as separator..."> <!--Used as seperator between each word-->
 <br><br>
 <input type="text" id="lWrapper" name="wrapper" placeholder="Left wrapper...">
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="rWrapper" name="wrapper" placeholder="Right wrapper...">
 <br><br> <!--Wrappers above are the first and last characters of the output (for example { and })-->
</form>
<button onclick="genCombi()">Click</button>
<br>
<p>Combinations: <span id="comboCount"></span></p>

<h2>The result:</h2>
<textarea id="textarea-r" rows="50" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="The result after clicking..."></textarea>
```

Basicly I hard-coded all input fields, the top 3 textarea's are to put in all words you want to combine, every linebreak (new line, enter key etc) will be split up. White spaces and spaces in your text will not count. Under there I added some fields like the seperators and wrappers, you could hard code a few buttons, but this works aswell. The button calls the function in the next bit, and the textarea-r shows the result after the function has been called. You could add an If statement to check if the seperator is empty, or just hard code it to be a white space.

```
<script>
function genCombi() {
    var array1 = document.getElementById('textarea-1').value.split('\n'); //Getting the textfield corresponding to the ID
    var array2 = document.getElementById('textarea-2').value.split('\n');
    var array3 = document.getElementById('textarea-3').value.split('\n');
    var resultArray = []; //Making of an empty array.
    var resultField = document.getElementById('textarea-r'); //Getting the result field
    var separator = document.getElementById('separator').value; //Getting the seperator
    var lWrapper = document.getElementById('lWrapper').value; //Getting of both wrappers
    var rWrapper = document.getElementById('rWrapper').value;
    for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {  //The for loops to go through the first result of the first textfield, then the second result and then to add all third results.
        for (x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < array3.length; y++) {
                resultArray.push(lWrapper + array1[i] + separator + array2[x] + separator + array3[y] + rWrapper);    //Pushing to the resultArray we defined before.  
            }
        }
    }
    resultField.value = resultArray.join("\n"); //Adding every single array row to a new row in the resultfield, hence the "\n"
    document.getElementById("comboCount").innerHTML = resultArray.length; //Checking howmany rows we have and adding them to the combination counter span. Could also add a var to the first for loop and use that.
}   
</script>
```

What we do up here is loop through every entry one by one, and adding the second and third entry. I will zoom in a little closer on the for loops:

What we do down here is as follows: We get to the first loop, while still on the first iteration we go to the second loop, while still on that first iteration we go to the third loop. The third loop goes through all entries possible, and then goes back to the second loop. When the second loop is done, it goes back to the first loop. More or less we are working from front to back by doing this.

```
  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
        for (x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < array3.length; y++) {
                resultArray.push(lWrapper + array1[i] + separator + array2[x] + separator + array3[y] + rWrapper); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I know this will not be the best solution, the HTML part of this you can use as example (but I do not suggest using the 
 tags as spacing). The probably are better solutions to do this, but in my opinion, this one is easy to make, easy to understand and easy to extend if needed.

For instance, you could add another text field by making a button that creates another element, or use a PHP for, while or any other kind of loop (if you work in Wordpress for example) to dynamically add more field.

If you want to run the function when input is detected on the form, you can add oninput="genCombi()" to the form tag:

At last, I hope the code is useful to you, and if there are any questions about it, like how it works, or how you edit / extend / change certain parts, let me know.

Working snippet + code:

```js
function genCombi() {
        var array1 = document.getElementById('textarea-1').value.split('\n'); //Getting the textfield corresponding to the ID
        var array2 = document.getElementById('textarea-2').value.split('\n');
        var array3 = document.getElementById('textarea-3').value.split('\n');
        var resultArray = []; //Making of an empty array.
        var resultField = document.getElementById('textarea-r'); //Getting the result field
        var separator = document.getElementById('separator').value; //Getting the seperator
        var lWrapper = document.getElementById('lWrapper').value; //Getting of both wrappers
        var rWrapper = document.getElementById('rWrapper').value;
        for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {  //The for loops to go through the first result of the first textfield, then the second result and then to add all third results.
            for (x = 0; x < array2.length; x++) {
                for (y = 0; y < array3.length; y++) {
                    resultArray.push(lWrapper + array1[i] + separator + array2[x] + separator + array3[y] + rWrapper);    //Pushing to the resultArray we defined before.  
                }
            }
        }
        resultField.value = resultArray.join("\n"); //Adding every single array row to a new row in the resultfield, hence the "\n"
        document.getElementById("comboCount").innerHTML = resultArray.length; //Checking howmany rows we have and adding them to the combination counter span. Could also add a var to the first for loop and use that.
    }
```

```html
<form action="" id="combiForm" oninput="genCombi()">
    <textarea id="textarea-1" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="Each enter makes a new input line..."></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea-2" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="Each enter makes a new input line..."></textarea>
    <textarea id="textarea-3" rows="4" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="Each enter makes a new input line..."></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="separator" name="separator" placeholder="Input will be used as separator...">
    <br><br>
    <input type="text" id="lWrapper" name="wrapper" placeholder="Left wrapper...">
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="rWrapper" name="wrapper" placeholder="Right wrapper...">
    <br><br>
</form>
<button onclick="genCombi()">Click</button>
<br>
<p>Combinations: <span id="comboCount"></span></p>

<h2>The result:</h2>
<textarea id="textarea-r" rows="50" cols="50" name="comment" placeholder="The result after clicking..."></textarea>
```

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/s5hby8

Ps: If anybody find any bugs or can prettify / make this code better, go ahead.

Comment: Master Jarvic, you have my thanks! Great work of code and I appreciate the extensive explanation.